# Incrementing a CSS style percentage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I recently made a Whack-a-Mole game and I'm really proud of my progress but there's a problem with the game. The problem is that I want to make the moles go up by updating the bottom percentage but I don't know how to do this.

I tried to solve this with a simple code:

```
function goup() {
   mole.style.bottom += 5%
}
```

It didn't work so I tried to replace the 5% with `5 + "%"` but it is still don't working.

How can I add two percentages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mole.style.bottom` is a string with a `"%"` sign on the end, so you'll need to chop off the percent sign and parse the number, do your math to create the new value, then re-attach the percent sign:

```js
const moleSpeed = 0.2;
  
(function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  
  const el = document.querySelector(".mole");
  const oldPercent = +(el.style.bottom || "0%").slice(0, -1);
  el.style.bottom = (oldPercent + moleSpeed) + "%";
})();
```

```css
.mole {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="mole">mole</div>
```

This works, but keeps state in the DOM. That's generally a poor design strategy:

- Bidirectional data flowing between the UI and the game logic is hard to understand
- Serialization/deserialization to/from the DOM is verbose, error-prone and harmful to performance
- The game's internal logic is tightly coupled to a specific UI API. It'd have to be rewritten to use the canvas API instead of the DOM, for example.

A better solution is to keep all game state in JS and use one-directional rendering to dump the state to the DOM after all game state has been updated per frame. For example:

```js
const mole = {
  bottom: 0,
  speed: 0.2,
};

(function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  mole.bottom += mole.speed;
  const el = document.querySelector(".mole");
  el.style.bottom = mole.bottom + "%";
})();
```

```css
.mole {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="mole">mole</div>
```

Of course, in an actual animation or game, you'll probably need more design to represent a mole with all of its relevant methods than this simple proof-of-concept shows. The important point is that the game logic and UI are decoupled, so we don't have to traverse the DOM and parse a string just to figure out where a mole is located.